# apply a transition on each object in a D3 selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, each

I'm having troubles in understanding how to get each D3 object in a selection to apply a transition.
Consider the follwoing code (here on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtc8feay/1/)):

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var dataSet = [10, 20, 30, 40];

var circle = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr("r",function(d){ return d })
    .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return i * 100 + Math.random()*50 })
    .attr("cy",50)
    .attr("fill",'red')
   ;

circle.each(function(d,i) {
    this
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("cx",this.cx+100);
})
```

My use of `this` is wrong. I've also tried with `d3.select(this)` but I get the dom object corresponding to D3 object. 
I'm unable to get the D3 object to apply transition.

Comment: `this` is the element (not the selection), so you could use `d3.select(this).transition()` to initiate the transition - but it isn't clear why you want to use `.each` since a transition is made for each element when using `selection.transition()` : https://jsfiddle.net/dtc8feay/

Comment: @Andrew, you are right. If I can use selectAll(..).transition(), I will do it. But I need to access .cx property of the circles, because in my real case each transition has different parameters. I have updated my question according to such needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing part is that you can supply a function to `.attr('cx', function (d,i) { ... })` when using a transition, and inside that function you can access the `cx` attribute using `this.getAttribute('cx')`.

Of course, you also want to make sure to turn it into a number using `parseInt()`, otherwise it will do string concatenation (because JS, sigh).

So change your final line to:

```
circle.transition().duration(1000).attr('cx', function(d, i) {
  return parseInt(this.getAttribute('cx')) + 100;
});
```